# Why can't I generate all permutations with std::next_permutation?

Tags: c++, stl, c++14, permutation

I'm trying to obtain all permutations of binary values (which, in this case, are represented by integers 0 and 1) using the [std::next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) from the C++14 STL.

However, I do think that I found a bug in this method.
If the vector has **one or more zeros** on its **end**, then one **cannot** obtain all permutations of the vector.

For instance, let's consider the vector `std::vector<int> a = {1,0,0}`. The only permutation found by `std::next_permutation` is `{(1 0 0)}`, whereas there exists three possible permutations `{(1 0 0), (0 1 0), (0 0 1)}`.

Is this a bug? If so, where can I report it?

You can access my code in C++ shell [here](http://cpp.sh/9xago). It is also displayed below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

  std::vector<int> a = {1,0,0,0};
  std::vector<int> b = {0,0,0,1};

  std::cout << "Permutations of a" << std::endl;
  do {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
      std::cout << a[i];
    }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  } while (std::next_permutation(a.begin(), a.end()));
  
  
  std::cout << std::endl << "Permutations of b" << std::endl;
  
  do {
    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
      std::cout << b[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  } while (std::next_permutation(b.begin(), b.end()));
  exit(0);
}
```

Output:

```
Permutations of a
1000

Permutations of b
0001
0010
0100
1000
```

Comment: did you read any documentation before you concluded that it is a bug?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation

Comment: If `next_permutation` didn't stop after the last permutation, your loop would never end so it is indeed a feature.

Comment: don't try to guess what a function does by its name only, it can go wrong quite often (unfortunately)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation):

> Permutes the range [first, last) into the next permutation, where the set of all permutations is **ordered lexicographically** with respect to operator< or comp.

So iterating through the permutations will only give you the lexicographically increasing sequence from the initial range.

Note that the example at the bottom of the reference page does a `std::sort` on the initial range in order to generate *all* permutations.

Comment: The linked webpage is not "the reference", even if it is called like that (it is a very useful page, nevertheless).

Comment: @Acorn I usually use "reference", or even "wording"/"rules"/etc, without distinguishing between whether the link leads to `eel.is/c++draft` or `cppreference.com` (obviously only the former for `language-lawyer` questions). Do you think it needs to be clear from the text which one it is?

Comment: It isn't a big deal, but in general I avoid calling any web a "reference", much less *the* reference (unless it is the actual reference, of course). New C++ programmers may mistake it for official docs many other languages have. There are infamous examples like w3schools... In addition, cppreference it is a wiki that anybody can (could?) edit.

Answer (score 1):

From the C++20 standard [alg.permutation.generators]:

> *Effects:* Takes a sequence defined by the range `[first, last)` and transforms it into the next permutation. The next permutation is found by assuming that the set of all permutations is lexicographically sorted with respect to `comp` and `proj`. If no such permutation exists, transforms the sequence into the first permutation; that is, the ascendingly-sorted one.

Your `a` is already at the last permutation, so the function returns `false`. Just like it does when `b` reaches the same state.